# Upload a big PHP file to Google Drive

Tags: php, file-upload, google-drive-api

I am able to upload a big file from my server to Google drive, but when I'm uploading a file from my server, I can't access my website as long as the process is not done. Do you know what I can do about that?

There is my script for my upload:

```
set_time_limit(0);                    
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->title = "title";


$chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

// Call the API with the media upload, defer so it doesn't immediately return.
$client->setDefer(true);
$request = $service->files->insert($file);

// Create a media file upload to represent our upload process.
$media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
  $client,
  $request,
  mime_content_type($filePath),
  null,
  true,
  $chunkSizeBytes
);
$media->setFileSize(exec('stat -c %s "'.$filePath.'"'));
// Upload the various chunks. $status will be false until the process is
// complete.
$status = false;
$handle = fopen($filePath, "rb");
while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
  $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
  $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
 }

// The final value of $status will be the data from the API for the object
// that has been uploaded.
$result = false;
if($status != false) {
  $result = $status;                          

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Do you mean the website won't load? What do you mean by "can't access"?

Comment: try `session_write_close()` in the upload handler, assuming you're using standard file-based sessions, which would lock the session while the upload runs?

Comment: I'm not having any error all is going good, but i'm doing the upload on a web page and while my upload is in process i'm trying too go on my website with another page but the page won't load untill the upload is not done.

Comment: Sounds like marc could be right.

Comment: i did not try it..  i will and i'm getting you back with that sorry

Comment: i just tried it and it worked thank you so much... i did not think that would work

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what might be happening is that your connection to Google Drive might be hogging the bandwidth. The chances are that even if you are on a dedicated server that your internal network connection might be limited by design (many have a 10Mb connection) and often further by firewall restrictions.

Although it is possible that your server itself is simply maxed out sending the file it is not that likely.

As to what you can do about it that could be a tough nut to crack. At the PHP level I am not aware of sufficiently low level control over socket connections in terms of packet rate limits and so forth.

If you are able to implement a bandwidth restricted connection it could solve things for you but failing that there is always "Plan B for intensive operations" which is queue such actions for late at night when it is massively unlikely that anyone is actually going to want to access the site and if they are then you are disrupting the least amount of people.

An alternative is to use some sort of cloud DNS system with caching such as cloudflare which would keep your content being served up to people even while the server drops out for a moment to do the big job.

Combine the two together and although the server stops responding during the upload it is likely to go unnoticed. It is far from the perfect solution but in terms of designing around something that might not be solvable it would be a solid working answer.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i will try to find a solution with that

Comment: All the best. I am sorry I could not give you a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly, your problem is that your upload to Drive is blocking and until it completes you don't send a response to the browser. If that's the case, you need to delegate the Drive upload to a separate thread and let the primary thread send an http response and close.

Comment: hmmm i don't want to send a reponse to the user, this web page is only for me. But the problem is if i want to go on another page of my server i need to wait that the upload is done... probably because the upload is taking all the bandwidth? but strangely the first week i did not have this problem it started today... i don't know why

Comment: I really doubt it's bandwidth if you are on a hosted server. If you suspect that bandwidth is an issue, you can simple switch to using resumable upload with chunks. If the file is large, you should be using resumable anyway, so chunking isn't much of an extra step.

Comment: i'm using chunks and i have 50mb connection